# Trouble iterating over js objects to set them in groups per object in different div tags

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, axios

Trying to create a website that takes in information from an API, however I don't really understand how to do it seeing that I need all results grouped up and the API I've created almost never gives a response with the same amounts of objects. So the question is, seeing that I use vue.js and axios is there any way to loop through the json objects to show each of the objects in a seperate ? I manage to do it when there are a specified amounts, but I want to make it dynamic so I don't hardcode into the variables what part of the response I need to set to each variable.

This is the structure of the JSON

```
[
    {
        "JTranslate": {
            "translationId": "dictionary.bokmaal",
            "lemmata": [
                {
                    "lemma": "båt",
                    "meanings": [
                        {
                            "meaning": "(liten) farkost",
                            "meaningText": "(liten) farkost"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "fartøy, skip",
                            "meaningText": "fartøy, skip"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "noe som ligner på en båt (1,2)",
                            "meaningText": "noe som ligner på en båt (1,2)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "paradigms": {
                        "paradigm": "subst mask appell"
                    },
                    "inflections": {
                        "inflection": "ent ub",
                        "inflectionForms": [
                            "båten",
                            "båter",
                            "båt",
                            "båtene"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "JTranslate": {
            "translationId": "dictionary.nynorsk",
            "lemmata": [
                {
                    "lemma": "båt",
                    "meanings": [
                        {
                            "meaning": "(liten) farkost til å ro el. til å drive fram med segl el. motor",
                            "meaningText": "(liten) farkost til å ro el. til å drive fram med segl el. motor"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "farty, skip",
                            "meaningText": "farty, skip"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "noko som i forma minner om ein båt",
                            "meaningText": "noko som i forma minner om ein båt (1)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "paradigms": {
                        "paradigm": "subst mask appell"
                    },
                    "inflections": {
                        "inflection": "eint ub",
                        "inflectionForms": [
                            "båt",
                            "båten",
                            "båtar",
                            "båtane"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "JTranslate": {
            "translationId": "dictionary.bokmaalTilNynorsk",
            "lemmata": [
                {
                    "lemma": "båt",
                    "meanings": [
                        {
                            "meaning": "(liten) farkost",
                            "meaningText": "(liten) farkost"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "fartøy, skip",
                            "meaningText": "fartøy, skip"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "noe som ligner på en båt (1,2)",
                            "meaningText": "noe som ligner på en båt (1,2)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "paradigms": {
                        "paradigm": "subst mask appell"
                    },
                    "inflections": {
                        "inflection": "ent ub",
                        "inflectionForms": [
                            "båten",
                            "båter",
                            "båt",
                            "båtene"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "JTranslate": {
            "translationId": "dictionary.nynorskSynonym",
            "lemmata": [
                {
                    "lemma": "båt",
                    "meanings": [
                        {
                            "meaning": "(liten) farkost til å ro el. til å drive fram med segl el. motor",
                            "meaningText": "(liten) farkost til å ro el. til å drive fram med segl el. motor"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "farty, skip",
                            "meaningText": "farty, skip"
                        },
                        {
                            "meaning": "noko som i forma minner om ein båt",
                            "meaningText": "noko som i forma minner om ein båt (1)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "paradigms": {
                        "paradigm": "subst mask appell"
                    },
                    "inflections": {
                        "inflection": "eint ub",
                        "inflectionForms": [
                            "båt",
                            "båten",
                            "båtar",
                            "båtane"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**UPDATE:** Also should be added, when I say JSON object I actually ment js object. the json.parse() has been used on the json.

**UPDATE 2:**
This is what I've done, I've basically split it into 4 objects. And each object is called dependant of the choices done on the website.
For showing the information I've basically just done a bunch of nested v-fors but as I'm extracting more and more data from it gives a messy result. I do not have access to the code I had as I deleted the faulty code, saved the document and took a break from work. So I can't access that anymore.

But just for clarification, this is what I'm trying to extract:
For every lemmata I need lemma, all the meaningText within meanings. paradigm inside paradigms and all of the inflections

Comment: Can you share what you have coded so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having a problem with iterating over multiple json objects and showing them in div with vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805433/having-a-problem-with-iterating-over-multiple-json-objects-and-showing-them-in-d)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what do you want to do. Usually, only arrays contains 'dynamic' number of objects - therefore, you can use simple `forEach`, just like for ordinary JS array. If you want to iterate through object, you can simply treat them as dictionaries and try to obtain pairs of keys and values.
https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries